# VSCode Intellisense Completion - Assembly Language

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using VSCode to write in 6510 assembly language for C64, and I'm running into a problem with Intellisense.  I'm using the [Kick Assembler C64 for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=paulhocker.kick-assembler-vscode-ext).  So I expected the 6510 assembly mnemonics to be recognized, which it seems like they are.  The problem I'm running into is after typing the three letter opcode mnemonic and hitting tab to select it, the cursor moves one space past it (which is fine), but then Intellisense immediately starts making suggestions, so that I cannot hit the tab key again to create the space I'd like between the opcode mnemonic and the operand.

Is there a way to make Intellisense hold off on making suggestions until after I've typed that first character of the operand?  I'd rather not turn it off completely and slow myself way down.

Thanks,

Comment: https://gitlab.com/retro-coder/commodore/kick-assembler-vscode-ext/-/issues Report to its developers.

Comment: Done.  We'll see if they get back to me.  I'm liking VS Code pretty well, but that aspect is a little annoying.